# Property 'valeur' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

when I use `slice:0:16` on an `ngFor` like this:

```
<td class="align-middle" *ngFor="let valuerDuHier of data.list | slice:0:16; let i=index">
     <b>{{valuerDuHier?.valeur}}</b>
</td>
```

I get this error:

```
Error: src/main/webapp/app/xx/xx/my.component.html:51:64 - error TS2339: Property 'valeur' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

51                                             <b>{{valuerDuHier?.valeur}}&nbsp;</b>
                                                                  ~~~~~~

  src/main/webapp/app/xx/xx/my.component.ts:13:18
    13     templateUrl: "./xx.component.html",
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MyComponent.
                                                                      ~~~~~~
```

Comment: You're spelling is using both 'valuer' and 'valeur'; is this the issue, or intentional?

Comment: no this is not the issue when I remove this slice:0:16 its works fine

Comment: What is the datatype for `valuerDuHier`? It doesn't seem like your initial array is defined properly.

Comment: valuerDuHier is string

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui please replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share back! [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uq3ivt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)